# Creating the subdomain in Aws route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

I am using AWS, route 53 service for creating Sub Domain. I need to create sub-domain for my elastic ip, i have created a hosted zone which is in public and attached a Name server and A record to the main hosted zone. while testing it doesnot respone my elastic ip.
example: Domain registration: example.com
subdomain: test.example.com

I rechecked it for 10 times the records, elastic ips are all correct,
In the main Hosted Zone i attached two records of subdomain A and NS, did i need miss anything?

Comment: If I may ask, is elastic IP free of charge and also does it require some configurations as well?

Comment: @quintumnia EIP is free as long as it is attached to a running instance. You get charged if it is detached or servers are stopped. Also no additional changes are needed to server config. You just need to associate it with the server.

Comment: @CloudWanderer ,Oh okay that's cool.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Domain purchased from AWS or 3rd party like godaddy/ hostgator? If purchased from 3rd party, check [how to add](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-in-use.html) NS records from 3rd party to AWS hosted zone.

Also, if your domain was purchased less than 24 hrs ago, wait few more hours for it to get propagated

Once this process is done, create A record for your sub-domain

Comment: Thank you, it took time to reflects the changes.

Comment: Glad to be helpful
Yep. DNS things take some time to reflect. My own domain took almost 24+ hrs to go live.